# Template specialization for templated class

Tags: c++, templates

I've been looking at many other questions that talk about template specialization and I just can't seem to find the answer to my problem. I have read that you can't partially specialize function templates. So what would be a work around for the following.

Consider a function named `type`. This function is meant to return a single `char` denoting its type. As you build your classes you will have to "overload" or specialize the function `type` so that a function named `print_type` can print the type of the object without us having to call the function `type`. Here is some code:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

template<class T> inline char type(const T&) {return 'S';}
template<> inline char type(const int&) {return 'I';}
template<> inline char type(const double&) {return 'R';}

template<class T>
void print_type(T& t) {
    printf("Type = %c\n", type(t));
}

// OTHER FUTURE TYPES
template<> inline char type(const std::string&) {return 'W';}
template<class T> inline char type(const std::vector<T>&) {return 'T';}

int main() {
    int x;
    printf("Int type: %c\n", type(x));
    print_type(x);

    double y;
    printf("Double type: %c\n", type(y));
    print_type(y);

    std::string str;
    printf("String type: %c\n", type(str));
    print_type(str);

    std::vector<int> vtor;
    printf("Vector type: %c\n", type(vtor));
    print_type(vtor);
}
```

Notice that I have define specialized `type` for the `std::string`. Somehow it seems that it isn't possible to do with `std::vector<T>` of some type `T`. The result of running the above code gives:

```bash
macbook-pro:~ jmlopez$ ./a.out 
Int type: I
Type = I
Double type: R
Type = R
String type: W
Type = W
Vector type: T
Type = S
```

The `print_type` function wasn't able to pick up the definition for `std::vector<std::string>` and it simply default to original template function I defined. What would be a work around for this? Keep in mind that I must be able to define `type` for some other unknown types in some possible future and thus I cannot declare the function `print_type` after all the definitions of `type` have been set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The canonical work-around for not being able to partially specialize a function template is to delegate to partially specialized class templates, probably with suitable `static` member functions. For example:

```
template <typename> struct type_aux { static char type() { return 'S'; } };
template <> struct type_aux<int> { static char type() { return 'I'; } };
template <> struct type_aux<double> { static char type() { return 'R'; } };
template <> struct type_aux<std::string> { static char type() { return 'W'; } };
template <typename T> struct type_aux<std::vector<T>> {
    static char type() { return 'T'; }
}

template <typename T> char type(T const&) { return type_aux<T>::type(); }
```

Just to explain why your approach doesn't work the way you wrote it: the function template `template <typename T> char type(std::vector<T> const&)` would need to be found during instantiation of `print_type()`. However, at this point functions are only found with argument dependent look-up which won't go looking where you defined it. You could make your function template found if you'd declared it in `namespace std` but you are not allowed to do so. The specialization approach entirely side-steps the problem of having to locate functions.

Comment: Is there a substantial overhead by doing this? I think I will use this for objects that cannot be specialized, like `std::vector`. For the `std::string` we can simply specialize the function type. Thank you.

Comment: Add some space in `type_aux<std::vector<T> >`.

Comment: @jmlopez: if you make the `static` members `inline` there won't be any run-time overhead at all. There may a bigger footprint for the symbol names but it isn't that dramatic, really (whether it matters depends on how often you end up using these functions where they can't be inlined).

Comment: @jmlopez: yes, if you need to compile with a C++03 compiler, you'll need to have a space between the `>>`. However, with C++11 (the current standard since more than 2 years) the space isn't necessary.

Comment: oh dear, I am living in the past. Question, aren't the static functions already inline since they are being defined inside the struct? I thought they didn't get to be inline if their implementation was placed outside the declaration.

Comment: @jmlopez: yes, they are `inline` in the semantic sense, i.e., they won't create conflicting symbols between different translation units. However, some compilers won't necessarily attempt to `inline` member functions defined in the class definition without the `inline` keyword to nudge them on. Whether that is the case with the compiler you are using I don't know. If you are paranoid about overheads, you might want to declare them `inline` just in case...